# Eventhandler error in C# Visual Studio 11 for metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am using VisualStudio 11 beta for windows 8 metro apps development, I have a error.
Error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
   'System.EventHandler<Windows.UI.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs>' to 
   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationStartedEventHandler'
```

and my code is.

```
selectRectangle.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(OnRectangleManipulationStarted);
ellipseTL.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(OnRectangleManipulationStarted);
```

Comment: It isn't WPF anymore, wrong event handler type.  The delegate type is ManipulationStartedEventHandler in Metro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with VS 2012 for Metro yet, but from what I understand, Metro/.NET 4.5 does a bit of reorganization of namespaces, or at least the selectRectangle/ellipseTL.ManipulationStarted events use a different class.  Certainly in this case, they're looking for a `ManipulationStartedEventHandler` not an `EventHandler<>`.

Try this instead:

```
selectRectangle.ManipulationStarted += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationStartedEventHandler(OnRectangleManipulationStarted);
ellipseTL.ManipulationStarted += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationStartedEventHandler(OnRectangleManipulationStarted);
```

Or use the implicit event handler syntax:

```
selectRectangle.ManipulationStarted += OnRectangleManipulationStarted;
ellipseTL.ManipulationStarted += OnRectangleManipulationStarted;
```

But like I said, I haven't worked with the new API yet, so this is just a best guess from my experience with 4.0.

EDIT: You might also need to change the signature of your OnRectangleManipulationStarted method to match the ManipulationStartedEventHandler signature.

Comment: Could you post the using statements that you have at the top of the code file along with the method signature of OnRectangleManipulationStarted and indicate what class selectRectangle and ellipseTL are?

Comment: yes u right sir, i done it.
really thanx for help sir. i used wrong signature.

Comment: No problem.  Please mark the answer as correct and enjoy your time on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Array.Copy(Source.Pixels, SourceIndex, Result.Pixels, DestIndex, Width);
please help me in this too.
error with .Pixels

Comment: @Jud, Can't really tell without seeing your code, the specific error, and the type of Source and Result.  Your best bet is to post a new question with all the relevant source code and object types.